# Cross compile dotnet core app from Windows to Linux

Tags: linux, windows, cross-compiling, asp.net-core-1.0, kestrel-http-server

I am working in Windows and want to build a **dotnet core app** on Windows to run on Linux. In the build folder, I see .DLL file references in the published folder, which would obviously not work on Linux - how do I compile the app from my Windows environment to run on Linux? Is it possible?

In the project.json file there is runtime versions specified, which I believe correlates to the runtimes in the C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.0-preview2-003121\runtimes location? If so, how do I get the Linux runtime installed in Windows and reference it?

Comment: You can read about it over here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tutorials/using-with-xplat-cli

Answer (score 8):

You can create self contained applications using publish command.

For example (.Net Core 2.0):

```
dotnet publish -c release -r win7-x64
dotnet publish -c release -r centos.7-x64
```

You need to specify win7-x64 OR centos.7-x64 in `RuntimeIdentifiers` also in the `.csproj` file.

[For more help check this page](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/SelfcontainedNETCoreApplications.aspx).